# BracketAlignmentStyle: Break before closing parenthesis

Tags: c++, clang-format

Combining the **AlignAfterOpenBracket** (`BracketAlignmentStyle`) option with `BinPackArguments` and `BinPackParameters` set to `false`, it's possible to get the following formatting:

```
someShortFunction(argument);
someVeryVeryVeryLongFunction(
    argument1,
    argument2,
    argument3,
    argument4);
```

However, similar to `BreakBeforeBraces`, I'd like to break before the closing parenthesis:

```
someShortFunction(argument);
someVeryVeryVeryLongFunction(
    argument1,
    argument2,
    argument3,
    argument4
);
```

Is this possible with the existing options?

Answer (score 11):

It's not possible with the current clang options. However, there is a [patch](https://reviews.llvm.org/D33029) proposed that adds this change. It was stale for a long time, so it probably wouldn't get added any time soon. You still can use the patched version for your purposes. [Here](https://github.com/lucidsoftware/clang) is a clang fork with the patch applied.