# How to force clang-format break after variable type?

Tags: c++, c, code-formatting, clang-format, astyle

I couldn't make `clang-format` make code like this

```cpp
static inline return_type_t
foo(
     long_name_arg1_t **a,
     arg2_t b,
     arg3_t *c
) {
     var_type_t 
         var1,
         var2,
         var3;

     var_type_t const
         constant = 3;
}

global_var_t const
     var = {
          .arg1 = 1,
          .arg2 = 2,
     };
```

I have a big project with such style, it is old and I cannot use another code style, but I a bit tired to format code by hands. Is there way to force `clang-format` make:

- Unconditional break after variable type + some indentation for var name
- Unconditional break BEFORE closing paretheses in function declaration

**UPD:**
Edited to satisfy SO policies.

Comment: Please, DO NOT advise me use another style. I need EXACTLY this one and I don't need answers like "it's ugly!".

Comment: It is not just ugly, more to the point it is quite hard to read. Please don't follow dogma if you can make an improvement.

Comment: Tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. That being said, there was a nice little open source prog "UniversalIndent" which let you pick from various beautifiers (GNU indent etc) and see which one suited you best. Doesn't look like it is maintained much nowadays, but then coding styles haven't changed for many decades either.

Comment: At first, I disagree that's it is hard to read. It is super readable when you get used to it. Secondly, I have big code base and I just cannot change all the code. Technically, I can, but in real like I just will not pass code review.

Comment: Using an unorthodox style not used by any other programmer in the world is a really bad idea, no matter how good it is "once you get used to it". For the very same version as inventing your own spoken language which only you understand is a bad idea.

Comment: Or inventing your own file formats and data tx protocols...

Comment: @Lundin I work with proprietary project, which was starter about 20 years ago. It is not my choice to write in this style and I don't care about "other world" while working with this project.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's tradition to name such coding styles after the garage in which they are used :)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I have no idea. It seems it is some modification of GNU style. https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_chapter/indent_1.html

Comment: Just to notice, I do not ask for some really weird. I need only two additional formatting features. One of them has been being awaited for 3 years!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288556/bracketalignmentstyle-break-before-closing-parenthesis

Comment: Should not be a surprise to discover that such a heteroclite coding style lacks an available formatting utility.  You may need to write one yourself.

Comment: @Eljay Yes it seems so...

Comment: I support Pavels question about how to configure a widely used tool for a specific outcome. a) this kind of questions about widely used programming related tools ARE on topic on StackOverflow b) questioning whether the needed outcome is wise is NOT an answer c) Pavel had to focus on a specific tool (I agree), but answers are still free to mention how exactly it can be achieved with a different one